# MissingSchema: Invalid URL "/": No schema supplied

Tags: python

I want to retrieve data from google links so I followed this but the above error is coming.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from urllib.parse import quote
qstr = quote("postal code paris")
url_getallfolders = "https://www.google.co.in/?client=safari"+qstr
x = urlopen(url_getallfolders)
data = x.read()
import requests
response=requests.get(x)
response.content
```

Comment: What is x?  `requests.get()` expects a url string such as `"http://example.com/foo/bar"`.

Comment: Yes this is correct but passing a URL is generating a json file which not getting converted to text file as it is giving an error

Answer (score 1):

Why you're passing `X` ? try to get the type of x `type(x)` which is the HTTP Client response object not an URL. `<class 'http.client.HTTPResponse'>`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from urllib.parse import quote
qstr = quote("postal code paris")
url_getallfolders = "https://www.google.co.in/?client=safari"+qstr
x = urlopen(url_getallfolders)
data = x.read()
import requests
response=requests.get(url_getallfolders) # X is not an URL
response.content
```

Comment: This URL generated is giving the homepage of google whereas I want the search result page how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that you have an invalid URL.
Try to just print the URL to make sure they are getting read correctly before passing them to requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing frameworks here.
 [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is one library
 and [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html)
 is a different one. If you print `data` then you will see the correct html document.
these are two alternative approaches not to be mixed.

alternative 1:

```
req = urllib.request.Request('https://www.google.co.in/search?q=searc',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
x = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data = x.read()
print(data)
```

alternative 2

```
import requests
response=requests.get(req.full_url)
response.content
```

Comment: This URL generated is giving the homepage of google whereas I want the search result page how to do that?